# All RewriteCond domains go through the second default RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

UPDATE: All RewriteCond domains go through the second default RewriteRule, instead of going to their own RewriteCond, then RewriteRule. All URL's that I go to default to the /template/home.php. I know you can put in multiple domains in a single .htaccess, but I have not been able to get this .htaccess to direct different domains to their default paths. This has left me scratching my head.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)(.+)(firstDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=SLUG:%1,E=DOMAIN:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/home.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)\.on\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=SLUG:%1,E=DOMAIN:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/landing.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

What happends when you negate the first condition like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)(.+)(firstDomain)(\..+) !^www.secondDomain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/home.php [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)\.on\.(secondDomain)(\..+) !^www.firstDomain.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /template/landing.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: You made me realize something here. I missed another RewriteRule in my example (that I updated above) and that maybe RewriteRule's can't be a long list after a RewriteCond as is done in programming?

Comment: Just realized that chaining is required to continue down the list of RewriteRule's after passing a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond` is applicable to very next `RewriteRule` only. So you will need to have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)(.+)(firstDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SLUG:%1,E=DOMAIN:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstDomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ template/home.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.[^\.]+)\.on\.(secondDomain)(\..+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=SLUG:%1,E=DOMAIN:%{HTTP_HOST}]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondDomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ template/landing.php [L]
```